# Sum to Product Trig Identities

Tags: trigonometry

All,

I was enjoying sum to product trig identities in Mathematica, smiling that it was going well, producing the same answers trig students get by hand.

```
Sin[α] + Sin[β] // TrigFactor
```

Answer:

```
2 Cos[α/2 - β/2] Sin[α/2 + β/2]
```

And my first example:

```
Sin[5 θ] - Sin[3 θ] // TrigFactor // Simplify
```

Answer:

```
2 Cos[4 θ] Sin[θ]
```

But then:

```
Cos[3 θ] + Cos[2 θ] // TrigFactor // Simplify
```

Answer:

```
2 Cos[θ/2]^2 (1 - 2 Cos[θ] + 2 Cos[2 θ])
```

Where the expected answer is $2\cos\frac{5\theta}{2}\cos\frac{\theta}{2}$.

Suggestions?

Comment: This doesn't really help but it is at least satisfying to note that `2 Cos[(5 \[Theta])/2] Cos[ \[Theta]/2] // TrigReduce` results in `Cos[2 \[Theta]] + Cos[3 \[Theta]]`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As the `TrigFactor` help page says under Possible issues:

> A trigonometric expression can be factored in many different ways

Looking at the [Wikipedia page of trigonometric identies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities) you can find many identities that can apply. For instance, there are double and triple angle identities that seem directly relevant in your `Cos[3 θ] + Cos[2 θ]` case.

If you want Mathematica to use a specific identity you could define a rule of your own:

```
cosSum = Cos[a_] + Cos[b_] :> 2 Cos[(a + b)/2] Cos[(a - b)/2];

Cos[3 θ] + Cos[2 θ] /. cosSum
(* 2 Cos[θ/2] Cos[(5 θ)/2] *)
```

In slightly more complex situations this might apply differently than you intended:

```
Cos[p] + Cos[3 θ] + Cos[2 θ] /. cosSum
(* Cos[3 θ] + 2 Cos[1/2 (p - 2 θ)] Cos[1/2 (p + 2 θ)] *)
```

Mathematica picks the first match it can find, but because `p` is not evidently related to `2 θ` that doesn't yield a very useful result.

Let's define a rule that only applies if the two cosines have arguments that are integer multiples of a common term:

```
cosSumMul = Cos[a_] + Cos[b_] /; Head[a/b] == Rational :> 2 Cos[(a + b)/2] Cos[(a - b)/2];
```

Applying the modified rule:

```
Cos[p] + Cos[3 θ] + Cos[2 θ] /. cosSumMul
(* Cos[p] + 2 Cos[θ/2] Cos[(5 θ)/2] *)
```

Different order:

```
Cos[3 θ] + Cos[p] + Cos[2 θ] /. cosSumMul
(* Cos[p] + 2 Cos[θ/2] Cos[(5 θ)/2] *)
```

Comment: Fabulous answer, applying the specific identity you want. Thanks.

Comment: For reference: the identity used by Sjoerd is one of the [prosthaphaeresis formulae](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html).